# Integer Check with Ternary

Tags: c#

How to check for integer in one line?

```
sample.AddRange(Statistics.Select(player => new Stats
                       {
                         SeasonFromYear = Convert.ToInt32(seasonFromYear)
                       }
```

This one is working for me.

```
int a;
SeasonFromYear = int.TryParse(seasonFromYear, out a) ? a : default(int);
```

But for every property i need to declare one variable like `a`. Without that is it possible to check in one line?

Something like this

```
 sample.AddRange(Statistics.Select(player => new Stats
                       {
                         SeasonFromYear = is integer ? then value : else default value 
                       }
```

Comment: Why not use something like: `int desiredSeasonFromYear = int.TryParse(cmbSeasonFromYear.SelectedValue.ToString(), out desiredSeasonFromYear) ? desiredSeasonFromYear : -1;` where _desiredSeasonFromYear_ is the result. It returns _-1_ when the conversion fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create extension method:

```
public static int ToInt(this string v)
{
    int a = 0;
    int.TryParse(v, out a);
    return a;
}
```

And then:

```
int number = "123".ToInt();
```

**Edit**

Or you can pass integer as out parameter:

```
public static bool ToInt(this string v, out int a)
{
    return int.TryParse(v, out a);  
}
```

usage:

```
int number = 0;
"123".ToInt(out number);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not necessary. If [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) fails, `a` will be set to `default(int)`. Just use:

```
int a;
int.TryParse(sessionFromYear, out a);
SeasonFromYear = a;
```

Or if you really want to do it in one line, you'd have to create you're own wrapper method:

```
public static int TryParseInline(string in) {
    int a;
    int.TryParse(sessionFromYear, out a);
    return a;
}

...

sample.AddRange(Statistics.Select(player => new Stats
{
    SeasonFromYear = Util.TryParseInline(seasonFromYear),
    ...
})
```

Comment: why not just `int.TryParse(sessionFromYear, out SessionFromYear)` ?

Comment: Thanks, What i really asked to make it in one line.

Comment: @Pawel `int.TryParse(sessionFromYear, out SessionFromYear)` because `SessionFromYear` could be a property.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int.TryParse(sessionFromYear, out SessionFromYear)
```

If `SessionFromYear` can be a property just create a method that will do what you need to do - e.g.:

```
public int ParseInt(string input)
{
    int value;
    int.TryParse(input, out value);

    return value;
}
```

and then you can use this method all over the place like this:

```
SessionFromYear = ParseInt(sessionFromYear);
```

if you want to make it really fancy you could even create an extension method on the string class and then just do something like `sessionFromYear.ToInt()`

Comment: This will return `bool` as value, but i actually needs the `int` value to be returned. Can u pls check my question again? I updated it

Comment: edited the response - just create a method that does what you need and then you can use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a safe cast and doing a null-coalescing check in a single line?

```
SeasonFromYear = seasonFromYear as int ?? default(int);
```

Comment: Thanks, will it return error if the int parse fails on `seasonFromYear as int`?

Comment: Safe casting will not return an error. However, this won't work as I described it. Integers are non-nullable, and cannot be cast like this.

Comment: What do you meant? So it wont return error. Will it work the way i need?

Comment: Sorry. To be clear: a safe cast will either return the desired type or a null. HOWEVER, safe casting will not work in this instance as a string can't be directly cast to an integer.

Comment: In order to do this in a single line, you'll need to write an extension or utility method that will take your string and return you an integer (default value if that conversion fails).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for one line just declare a in the TryParse:

`SeasonFromYear = int.TryParse(seasonFromYear, out int a) ? a : default(int);`

Put whatever default value you want where default(int) is.